# Why I get SQL error message based on Div color style?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, ado.net

I was verify if the boolean is True or False. If it false, it will change the server Name text to color red, if True, it doesn't change color. The SQL was able to read server Name that doesn't change text color but couldn't read the server Name colored red text and got SQL error message,

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'red'.

Here is the VB code:

```
Dim sqlConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SOCT").ConnectionString))
Dim strSqlSecondary As String = "SELECT [Name], [Compliance] FROM [dbo].[ServerOwners] where SecondaryOwner like @uid order by [name]"
Dim cmdSecondary As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSqlSecondary, sqlConn)

cmdSecondary.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", TNN.NEAt.GetUserID())

Dim dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Try
   sqlConn.Open()
   Dim root As TreeNode
   Dim rootNode As TreeNode
   Dim firstNode As Integer = 0
   'Load Primary Owner Node
   'Create RootTreeNode
   dr = cmdSecondary.ExecuteReader()

   If dr.HasRows Then
      'Load Secondary Owner Node
      'Create RootTreeNode
      root = New TreeNode("Secondary Owner", "Secondary Owner")
      TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Add(root)
      root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None

      rootNode = TreeViewGroups.Nodes(firstNode)
      'populate the child nodes
      While dr.Read()
         Dim child As TreeNode = New TreeNode(dr("Name"), dr("Name"))
         Dim complianceFlag As Boolean

         If Boolean.TryParse(dr("Compliance"), complianceFlag) Then
            ' Yes, compliance value is a Boolean, now set color based on value
            If Not complianceFlag Then
               child.Text = "<div style='color:red'>" + child.Text + "</div>"
            End If
        End If
        rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(child)
        child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
      End While
    dr.Close()
```

The error came from this line code because it read "red":

```
child.Text = "<div style='color:red'>" + child.Text + "</div>"
```

The child node text is passing when I click link to update,

```
Protected Sub LinkButtonConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonConfirm.Click
hide()
PanelCompliance.Visible = True
PanelDisplayGrid.Visible = True
'display the servers
Dim sqlConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SOCT").ConnectionString))
Dim strSql As New StringBuilder
strSql.Append("Select [Name] , [ApplicationName] , [Environment], [Description], [TechMgmtTeam] , [PrimaryOwner], [PPhone], [SecondaryOwner], [SPhone], [Queue], [Crit] from dbo.ServerOwners where")

'Loops Through all Selected items and appends to sql statement
Dim x As Integer = 0
For Each item As TreeNode In TreeViewGroups.CheckedNodes
If item.Depth = 0 Then
Else
   'append to select statement
    strSql.Append(" [Name]='" & item.Text & "' or ")
    x = x + 1
End If
Next

If x = 0 Then
   hide()
   LabelError.Text = "Please select at least one server in the left pane."
   PanelError.Visible = True
Else
   strSql.Append(" [Name]='Blank' order by [name]")
   Try
      sqlConn.Open()
      Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql.ToString(), sqlConn)
      Dim a As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
      Dim datTab As New DataTable
      a.Fill(datTab)

      Session("Table") = datTab

      GridViewDisp.DataSource = datTab
      GridViewDisp.DataBind()
   Catch ex As Exception
      hide()
      LabelError.Text = ex.ToString()
      PanelError.Visible = True
   Finally
      sqlConn.Close()
      sqlConn.Dispose()
   End Try
End If
End Sub
```

If I get rid of Div tag, everything is work fine except there won't be colored red. How they able to read Div style which they should ignore the style and focus on child text. Is there a way to fix?

Comment: There's something you are not telling us, like the sql that's being used to populate dr maybe...

Comment: I edited it by adding better detail as you request. I really think it had nothing to do with dr.... It something to do with div style **red** which SQL read it as text.

Comment: Are you storing the data back to the server with those single-quotes in it? That seems like a more likely place to get the error.

Comment: It shouldn't store single quote div style in SQL server. That was just to change text color.

Comment: I added codes above that pass child node text to SQL

Comment: If you use SQL parameters to pass the child node text to SQL then you will eliminate the problem.

Comment: It pass child node as String to LinkButtonConfirm_Click class then assign the child node in SQL parameter as Name

Comment: Ahh.. you probably want the child node text without the <div> decoration.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the Name in the .Tag property of the child, you get to be able to use it regardless of what you do to the .Text of the child:

```
While dr.Read()
    Dim myName as String = dr("Name")
    Dim child As TreeNode = New TreeNode(myName , myName)
    child.Tag = myName
```

Then in `LinkButtonConfirm_Click`

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
For Each item As TreeNode In TreeViewGroups.CheckedNodes
    If item.Depth <> 0 Then
        'append to select statement
        strSql.Append(" [Name]='" & CStr(item.Tag) & "' or ")
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next
```

But you should still be adding the `CStr(item.Tag)` as SQL parameters. You already have a counter `x` in the loop which you can use to construct parameter names ("@p0", "@p1" etc.).

**Edit:** which would result in the Click handler looking something like

```
Protected Sub LinkButtonConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonConfirm.Click
    hide()
    PanelCompliance.Visible = True
    PanelDisplayGrid.Visible = True
    'display the servers
    Dim sqlConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SOCT").ConnectionString))
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim strSql As New StringBuilder
    Dim qryBase = <sql>
                      SELECT [Name]
                            ,[ApplicationName]
                            ,[Environment]
                            ,[Description]
                            ,[TechMgmtTeam]
                            ,[PrimaryOwner]
                            ,[PPhone]
                            ,[SecondaryOwner]
                            ,[SPhone]
                            ,[Queue]
                            ,[Crit]
                        FROM dbo.ServerOwners
                        WHERE
                  </sql>.Value

    strSql.Append(qryBase & " ")

    'Loop through all Selected items and append to sql statement
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim nLastCheckedNode As Integer = TreeViewGroups.CheckedNodes.Count - 1
    For Each item As TreeNode In TreeViewGroups.CheckedNodes
        If item.Depth <> 0 Then
            'append to select statement
            Dim paramName As String = "@p" & x.ToString()
            strSql.Append("[Name] = " & paramName)
            If x <> nLastCheckedNode Then
                ' we have another node to look at, so add " OR "
                strSql.Append(" OR ")
            End If

            'TODO: set the correct SqlDbType and the correct .Size
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = paramName,
                                                      .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                                      .Size = 20,
                                                      .Value = CStr(item.Tag)})

            x += 1
        End If
    Next

    If x = 0 Then
        hide()
        LabelError.Text = "Please select at least one server in the left pane."
        PanelError.Visible = True
    Else
        strSql.Append(" ORDER BY [Name]")
        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = sqlConn
            cmd.CommandText = strSql.tostring()
            Dim a As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim datTab As New DataTable
            a.Fill(datTab)

            Session("Table") = datTab

            GridViewDisp.DataSource = datTab
            GridViewDisp.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            hide()
            LabelError.Text = ex.ToString()
            PanelError.Visible = True
        Finally
            sqlConn.Close()
            sqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Morton - Your theory are correct about error in `strSql.Append(" [Name]='" & item.Text & "' or ")` in `LinkButtonConfirm_Click`. I changed to `strSql.Append(" [Name]='" & item.Value & "' or ")` by replacing Text to Value. Now everything worked!